# could not broadcast input array from shape (20) into shape (19)

Tags: python, numpy, append, reshape

I have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist=[26, 26, 26,...., 290, 290,..290]
```

The # of unique numbers in mylist is 262. For every single unique number, there are 19 duplicates. So the # of 26 is 19, the number of 27 is also 19, etc,etc, the number of 290 is also 19.

So I have 262*19 elements in mylist.

I transform mylist into 262/19:

```
mylist= np.array(mylist).reshape((262, 19))
```

Now I'm trying to add one more element to every single row:

```
   for i in mylist:

    i = np.append(i, i[0])
```

It's saying that could not broadcast input array from shape (20) into shape (19)

Answer (score 0):

`i[0]` is a row. `i` is not going to make a difference in `mylist`. I have no idea what you mean inside *etc. etc.* But I am just guessing

```
mylist = np.outer(np.arange(26,291), np.ones(19))
```

then if you want to add something else as a column

```
mylist = np.hstack([mylist, np.arange(26,291)[:, None]])
```